# Visa renewal interview question

Tags: visas, usa

I am currently an international student under F1 status in the US. My F1 status will end 5 years from now, i.e. in May 2023, but my visa has expired 3 years ago in June 2015. I don't intend to go home until the summer before my F1 status expires, i.e. in June 2022. Will this make my interview during the visa renewal process harder? Will the interviewer assume that I don't intend to leave the US since I haven't come home for such a long time?

Comment: There is no way to know. One can only make guesses. June 2022 is still four years away! And your plans might change.

Comment: As a former F1 student I can tell you that the behavior you describe is quite common with F1 students. Don't worry about it **at all**. No consular officer is going to deny you a visa to return to finish one year of education after having spent six plus years acquiring that education.